# Is there any negatives to storing JSON in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, json, database, laravel-4

I am building a complex ordering system and I am struggling with whether I should store some of the more detailed information in a single column as JSON or if I should create the multiple tables and logic to keep JSON out of the picture.

Since each order will have multiple required dates, ship dates, parts, kits (collections of parts), and more. It just seems easier to store this as JSON of a single 'order'row.

Are there any major down sides to doing this?

Comment: Why not set up a relational schema for your orders, ie. kits are a collection of parts, so table 'kits' has a 1 to M with 'parts', 'orders' references a kit from 'kits', and so on...

Comment: The first one that comes to bind is searchability. You won't be able to search the data using a `WHERE` clause. At least not easily. Also, you won't be able to `JOIN` on any of the data inside the JSON object. The data becomes useless in terms of being able to add a column `INDEX` for any numerical data it may possess. It defeats the purpose of using a relational database. If this is a route you're looking to take, look at a NoSQL database like _MongoDB_. The information in that database is actually stored in objects that are formatted in JavaScript syntax (i.e. exactly what you want).

Comment: @War10ck I agree with MongoDB, unfortunately in this scenerio a new db is not an option. As for search ability, I am not to concerned. Is that the right though process, probably not.

Comment: @ElGavilan I understand what you are saying and that is my other option. There are a lot more variables in play that make this a complicated relational DB. regardless, this is the approach I feel I will need to take.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSON is geared more towards short term storage to send data from one thing to another.  It is horribly inefficient space and computationally wise for long term storage compared to a database.  You will also loose the ability to query the data directly without parsing it first (e.g "select * from table where orderdate < today").  You'll also have to develop your own tools to view the data, since if you try to view it in the database directly, everything will run together.

In short, this is almost always a really bad idea.

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for.